# LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS requests clang but directory not found

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, flang

```
C:\Flang\llvm-16\llvm-16.0.0\build2>cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="flang;clang" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Flang\FlangInstall" ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- Enabling MLIR as a dependency to flang
-- bolt project is disabled
-- clang project is enabled
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:196 (message):
  LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS requests clang but directory not found:
  C:/Flang/llvm-16/llvm-16.0.0/../clang


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am tring to execute the command above but it is showing the error as mentioned. I tried pasting Clang files in different directories but no success.

Comment: `clang` directory exists in the repo: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/llvmorg-16.0.0. Probably, your llvm sources are incomplete.